# Methods referenced by other assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, reference, system.reflection

I am developing a tool for Impact Analysis. If I am changing a method say "myMethod" in myAssembly, I need to get all other assemblies referencing myAssembly and I got it through below code.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("otherAssembly");
//check if the my Assembly is referenced or not?
if (a.GetReferencedAssemblies().Where(item => item.Name == "myAssembly").LongCount() > 0)
{
    //Do something
}
```

But here How can I know if "myMethod" of "myAssembly" is called/used or not? Otherwise I will get all other assemblies which are referencing myAssembly (say 10 in number) but out of 10 just 1 is called/used myMethod and will be impacted.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to analyze all code in those assemblies. You can use [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) for this task.

Some more info:
What you are trying to do isn't exactly trivial. You need to iterate over all possibly executable code and examine the CIL instructions and analyze them to see whether your method is called.
As a starting point, you can get the instructions of all methods like this:

```
var assemblyResolver = new DefaultAssemblyResolver();
assemblyResolver.AddSearchDirectory(...);
var assemblyDefinition = assemblyResolver.Resolve(
                             AssemblyNameReference.Parse(fullName));
foreach(ModuleDefinition module in assemblyDefinition)
{
    foreach(TypeDefinition type in module.Types)
    {
        foreach(MethodDefinition method in type.Methods)
        {
            foreach(Instruction instruction in method.Body.Instructions)
            {
                // Analyze it - the hard part ;-)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks alot for your suggestion. I am trying it and will update you soon on it.

Comment: @Daniel: With some changes (very specific to my requirment) it worked. Great Thanks alot. You rock.

Comment: @Shwetabh: That's nice to hear! Would you mind sharing the part that is missing in my suggestion, i.e. the real analysis?

Comment: @Daniel: As said it was very much specific to my requirment. To let you know:
1. I was already iterating all the dlls (100s in number). 
2. Then By my above code I am getting all the assemblies where are refering to my assembly.
3. Once I get say 10 assemblies by above then using code by passing directory and selected assembly fullname to get in instructions.
4. Then in Analyzing part (the toughest one) I am just looking for my method name (string operation).

Thats it.

Comment: @Shwetabh: Thanks for the update. You are aware, that this will lead to false positives, if there exist several methods with the same name in different classes?

Comment: @Daniel: body can be null, so added a check there.
foreach(MethodDefinition method in type.Methods)
     {
      if (method.Body != null)
      {
       foreach (Instruction instruction in method.Body.Instructions)
       {
        // Analyze it - the hard part ;-)
        //txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + "\n" + instruction.ToString();
        sb.Append(instruction);
       }
      }
     }

Comment: @Daniel: Got your point, do you have any suggestion. I can think of one, should we send method name as assemblyname.namespace.class.methodname? but this will not achieve what I want as I have overridden few methods in different classes :(

Comment: @Shwetabh: I don't really know CIL, so I can't say anything right now. I will try and find an answer.